# How can I copy appengine database from one application to another - java project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, copy

Last couple of days I was trying to copy data entities from one **appengine** application to another. I read that `this can't be done for Java application`. I made some more research to do that by cloud storage `patg` but found out that I can't do that between two applications.

Can anybody help on that, and what steps should I do that so can copy data entities from application to another, take in consideration that I want to do that from UI not code.

Now when I try to copy data from app1 to app 2 from Datastore admin it gives :

```
"There was a problem kicking off the jobs.
The error was:
Fetch to https://blablabla.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api failed with status 404
Back to Datastore Admin"
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Mohammed.

Comment: Have you set your target application’s Remote API URL correctly, and set up your target app to handle these calls?

Answer (score 3):

To restore backup data from a source application to a target application:

[Create an access control list (ACL)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#set-an-acl) on the source application's storage bucket with the following permission:

User
[PROJECT_ID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
Reader
where [PROJECT_ID] is the project ID of the target application.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring#restoring_data_to_another_app